# Creating ObjectId vs letting DB create it

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using labix mgo module as a Go Mongo driver. Since Go is concurrent (and parallel), is it safe to generate ObjectId in application or should only database do that?

It would be really straightforward if `.Insert()` could return `Id`. But this way when I need it, there are two approaches how I do that:

1) generate ObjectId on client and use it

```
...
user.ID = bson.NewObjectId()
Users.Insert(user)
// use user.ID normally
```

2) let the database generate the Id and retrieve it

```
...
Users.Insert(user)
Users.Find(user).One(&user)
// user user.ID normally
```

The second approach takes 2 database requests and the synchronous insert.

Question is: Is first approach safe as second is? Or is there something better I should be working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the first approach, as you will not need to retrieve any ID in this case.

If you will look at the description of [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), you will see that it consists of:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

As you see, even if you use the same machine running on one process (making 2 and 3 the same), you still are able to insert 3 bytes integer per second.

So if your writing speed is less than `(2^8)^3 - 1 = 16777215` per second, the collision will not happen.

And having 16 million inserts per second is too unrealistic.